# Matcher.group() not returning correct value when more than one pattern is combined

Tags: java, regex

I have the following code.

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("Group1 (.*), Group2=(\\[(.*)\\]|null) ,Group3=\\[(.*)\\] ,Group4=\\[(.*)\\]");
        String string = "Group1 12345, Group2=null ,Group3=[group3] ,Group4=[group4]";
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string);
        matcher.find();

        for (int i = 1; i <= matcher.groupCount(); i++) {
            System.out.println(i + ": " +matcher.group(i));
        }
        System.out.println();

        string = "Group1 12345, Group2=[group2] ,Group3=[group3] ,Group4=[group4]";

        for (int i = 1; i <= matcher.groupCount(); i++) {
            System.out.println(i + ": " +matcher.group(i));
        }
    }
}
```

Output given by the above code:

```
1: 12345
2: null
3: null
4: group3
5: group4

1: 12345
2: null
3: null
4: group3
5: group4
```

Question 1: Why am I getting the groupCount as 5? Is it due to multiple regex patterns combined (at Group2)?

Question 2: I expect the output be

```
12345
null
group3
group4

12345
group2
group3
group4
```

What should I do to print the output in my expected way.

Please help me understand the program correctly. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why 5 groups?

```
Group1 (.*), Group2=(\\[(.*)\\]|null) ,Group3=\\[(.*)\\] ,Group4=\\[(.*)\\]
       ^            ^   ^                        ^                  ^
       1            2   3                        4                  5
```

Basically, you just need to count the number of opening parentheses.

So that should explain your first output.

As for the second output, your matcher is still pointing to the first string. So you need to include:

```
string = "Group1 12345, Group2=[group2] ,Group3=[group3] ,Group4=[group4]";
matcher = pattern.matcher(string);
matcher.find();
```

before the last loop.

Finally, to get the expected output, I would simply use this:

```
Pattern.compile("Group1 (.*), Group2=\\[?(.*?)\\]? ,Group3=\\[(.*)\\] ,Group4=\\[(.*)\\]");
```

which is reasonably simple but loses the fact that Group2 needs brackets for non null values. If you want to keep that conditions, you will need to introduce a condition like `if (matcher.group(3).isEmpty()) { ... }`.

Pattern explanation for group 2:

```
\\[?  There may be an opening bracket or not, don't capture it
(.*?) Capture what's after "Group2=", excluding the brackets
\\]? There may be a closing bracket or not, don't capture it
```

Note, the `?` in `(.*?)` is [a lazy operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2301285/what-do-lazy-and-greedy-mean-in-the-context-of-regular-expressions) and is there to avoid capturing the closing bracket when there is one.

Comment: Thanks @assylias. I was so dumb not to add the statements that you have added before the second iteration. And my requirement was in perfect match with the pattern you have provided (I need non null values to be enclosed within brackets). However, can you please explain the pattern \\[?(.*)\\]? 
I couldn't understand how that is a combination of two regex patterns that I used in my example. Thanks

Comment: I've added an explanation at the bottom

Answer (score 1):

Two capturing groups correspond to your Group2 label :

```
(\\[(.*)\\]|null)
^---------------^
    ^--^
```

You could use a non-capturing group for the inner one :

```
(\\[(?:.*)\\]|null)
```

Or in this specific case, since the group seems useless (not used for later reference nor for applying a modifier to a group of token), you should just remove it :

```
(\\[.*\\]|null)
```